# Separating strings (list elements) with many spliters without loosing spliter from list

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, split

I want to separate list elements if list element contain any value from

```
list_operators = ['+', '-', '*', '(', ')']
```

without losing operator from list and without using regex.

For instance:

```
my_list = ['a', '=', 'x+y*z', '//', 'moo']
```

Wanted output :

```
['a', '=', 'x', '+', 'y', '*', 'z', '//', 'moo']
```

and x y z are words not one character:

```
['john+doe/12*5']

['john','+','doe','/','12','*','5']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to achieve this:

```
from itertools import groupby

operators = {'+', '-', '*', '(', ')'}
fragments = ['a', '=', 'x+y*z', '//', 'moo', '-', 'spam*(eggs-ham)']
separated = []
for fragment in fragments:
    for is_operator, group in groupby(fragment, lambda c: c in operators):
        if is_operator:
            separated.extend(group)
        else:
            separated.append(''.join(group))
```

```
>>> separated
['a', '=', 'x', '+', 'y', '*', 'z', '//', 'moo', '-',
 'spam', '*', '(', 'eggs', '-', 'ham', ')']
```

Note that I've changed the names of your variables to be a little more meaningful, and made `operators` a set because we only care about membership, not order (although the code would work just as well, if a little more slowly, with a list).

`groupby()` returns an iterable of `(key, group)` pairs, starting a new group whenever `key` changes. Since I've chosen a key function (`lambda c: c in operators`) that just tests for a character's membership in `operators`,  the result of the `groupby()` call looks something like this:

```
[
    (False, ['s', 'p', 'a', 'm']),
    (True, ['*', '(']),
    (False, ['e', 'g', 'g', 's']),
    (True, ['-']),
    (False, ['h', 'a', 'm']),
    (True, [')'])
]
```

(`groupby()` actually returns a *`groupby object`* made up of `(key,`*`grouper object`*`)` tuples - I've converted those objects to lists in the example above for clarity).

The rest of the code is straightforward: if `is_operator` is `True`, the characters in `group` are used to extend `separated`; if it's `False`, the characters in `group` are joined back into a string and appended to `separated`.

Comment: Thank you man! I hadn't see your comment about outer loop sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy way of doing it:

```
for x in my_list:
    if len(set(list_operators) & set(list(x)))!=0:
        for i in list(x):
            slist.append(i)
    else:
        slist.append(x)

slist
['a', '=', 'x', '+', 'y', '*', 'z', '//', 'moo']
```

Comment: This solution only works for the special case where each split element is one character long.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
import re
from itertools import chain

list_operators = ['+', '-', '*', '(', ')']
tokenizer = re.compile(r"[{}]|\w+".format("".join(map(re.escape, list_operators))))
my_list = ['a', '=', 'x+y*z', '//', 'moo', 'john+doe/12*5']
parsed = list(chain.from_iterable(map(tokenizer.findall, my_list)))
```

`parsed` result:

```
['a', 'x', '+', 'y', '*', 'z', 'moo', 'john', '+', 'doe', '12', '*', '5']
```